# Sumo polygons not visible in Veins Simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I am creating a 'T' intersection, with some buildings surrounding it. The simulation in SUMO-GUI works perfectly fine. When I import the simulation in veins and run it with some custom applications, the buildings doesn't appear in the veins simulation, when i run the .ini file. I tried simulation my experiment similar to veins-examples given, but nothing seems to work.

Below I have attached few files such that some can help me debug.

omnetpp.ini

```
 network = WirelessNetwork
 sim-time-limit = 120s
 debug-on-errors = true
 cmdenv-express-mode = true
 image-path = ../../../../images
 **.cmdenv-log-level = info
 print-undisposed = true
 **.scalar-recording = true
 **.vector-recording = true

 *.playgroundSizeX = 200m
 *.playgroundSizeY = 200m
 *.playgroundSizeZ = 50m

 # UDPBasicApp
 *.node[*].numApps = 1
 *.node[*].app[0].typename = "vanet.veins_inet.VeinsInetSampleApplication


 *.rsu[*].numApps = 1
 *.rsu[*].app[*].typename = "vanet.veins_inet.VeinsInetSampleApplicationRSU"


 # Ieee80211Interface

 *.node[*].wlan[0].opMode = "p"
 *.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandName = "5.9 GHz"
  *.node[*].wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 3
 *.node[*].wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 20mW
 *.node[*].wlan[0].radio.bandwidth = 10 MHz

 **.analogModel.ignorePartialInterference = true

 # RSUIeee80211Interface

 *.rsu[*].wlan[0].opMode = "p"

 *.rsu[*].wlan[0].radio.bandName = "5.9 GHz"
 *.rsu[*].wlan[0].radio.channelNumber = 3
 *.rsu[*].wlan[0].radio.transmitter.power = 20mW
 *.rsu[*].wlan[0].radio.bandwidth = 10 MHz

 # HostAutoConfigurator
 *.node[*].ipv4.configurator.typename = "HostAutoConfigurator"
 *.node[*].ipv4.configurator.interfaces = "wlan0"
 *.node[*].ipv4.configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.1"
 *.rsu[*].ipv4.configurator.typename = "HostAutoConfigurator"
 *.rsu[*].ipv4.configurator.interfaces = "wlan0"
 *.rsu[*].ipv4.configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.1"

 # VeinsInetMobility
 *.node[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobility"
 *.rsu[*].mobility.typename = "VeinsInetMobilityRSU"

 # VeinsInetManager
 *.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s
 *.manager.host = "localhost"
 *.manager.port = 9999
 *.manager.autoShutdown = true
 *.manager.launchConfig = xmldoc("t_intersection.launchd.xml")
*.manager.moduleType = "vanet.veins_inet.VeinsInetCar"

*.obstacles.obstacles = xmldoc("config.xml","//AnalogueModel[@type='SimpleObstacleShadowing']/obstacles")
```

.ned of the network

```
network WirelessNetwork
{
    parameters:
        double playgroundSizeX @unit(m); // x size of the area the nodes are in (in meters)
        double playgroundSizeY @unit(m); // y size of the area the nodes are in (in meters)
        double playgroundSizeZ @unit(m); // z size of the area the nodes are in (in meters)
        @display("bgb=$playgroundSizeX,$playgroundSizeY");
    submodules:
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            @display("p=3782.8613,2242.5125");
        }
        manager: VeinsInetManager {
            @display("p=2290.3037,2246.1887");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=1382.27,2246.1887");
        }
        
        roadsCanvasVisualizer: RoadsCanvasVisualizer {
            @display("p=3308.625,2246.1887");
        }
        
        node[0]: VeinsInetCar {
            @display("p=1044.055,2246.1887");
        }
        rsu[1]: VeinsInetRSU {
            @display("p=1661.665,2246.1887");
            
        }
        obstacles: ObstacleControl {
            @display("p=182.832,147.672");
        }
        world: BaseWorldUtility {
            parameters:
                playgroundSizeX = playgroundSizeX;
                playgroundSizeY = playgroundSizeY;
                playgroundSizeZ = playgroundSizeZ;
                @display("p=30,0;i=misc/globe");
        }
```

.poly.xml

```
<shapes>
    <poly id="poly_0" type="building" color="1.00,0.00,0.00" fill="1" layer="4" shape="38.460000,9.800000 77.690000,9.800000 77.690000,4.770000 38.460000,4.770000 38.460000,9.800000"/>
    <poly id="poly_1" type="building" color="1.00,0.00,0.00" fill="1" layer="4" shape="80.630000,10.220000 103.100000,10.220000 103.100000,4.770000 80.210000,4.770000 80.350000,10.360000"/>
    <poly id="poly_2" type="building" color="1.00,0.00,0.00" fill="1" layer="4" shape="32.330000,-6.740000 52.440000,-6.740000 52.440000,-23.630000 32.190000,-23.630000 32.190000,-6.880000 32.190000,-6.880000"/>
    
</shapes>
```

.sumo.cfg

```
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/sumoConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <net-file value="t_intersection.net.xml"/>
        <route-files value="t_intersection.rou.xml"/>
        <additional-files value="t_intersection.poly.xml"/>
    </input>

    <time>
        <begin value="0"/>
        <end value="1000"/>
        <step-length value="0.1"/>
    </time>

    <report>
        <xml-validation value="never"/>
        <xml-validation.net value="never"/>
        <no-step-log value="true"/>
    </report>

    <gui_only>
        <start value="true"/>
    </gui_only>

</configuration>
```

The sumo simulation looks like [image]

The view on veins looks as [image]

Can someone help me solving this?

Comment: You might not have included the obstacle types in the `config.xml` referenced from your `omnetpp.ini`

Answer (score 0):

*.annotations.draw = true

you need to add this in omnetpp.ini